Let $X \subset\mathbb R^n,$ $A, Y\subset X$ and $A$ closed. Prove that $A \cap Y$ is closed in $Y$
This is the exercise I'm trying to solve (sorry if it's simple but I'm trying to self-teaching myself General Topology)

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a given subset. $A, Y \subset X$ and $A$ closed in $X$. Prove that $A \cap Y$ is closed in $Y$.

This is my attempt: I know that a set $C \subset X$ is closed if $\, \, \forall x \in X - C, \exists \delta > 0: \forall y  \in C, d(x, y) \geq \delta$ (simply $X \, \backslash C$ is open). So what I'm trying to prove is that $\, \, \forall x \in Y-(A \cap Y), \exists \delta > 0: \forall y \in (A \cap Y), \, d(x, y) \geq \delta$ but I know that $Y - (A \cap Y) = Y \, \cap (X \, \backslash A)$ and because $A$ is closed in $X$ then $X \, \backslash A$ is open. This implies that $Y \cap (X \, \backslash A)$ is open, so this concludes the proof because I know that $Y \, \backslash (A \cap Y)$ is open, so $(A \cap Y)$ is closed in $Y$.
I don't know if this proof I gave here is right or if I've done some mistakes: I appreciate all helps and suggestions from you (sorry if I did some english mistakes, it's not my primary language)

"$X \setminus A$ is open. This implies that $Y \cap (X \setminus A)$ is open." Could you explain how you obtained this implication?

Your statement that $C\subset X$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $X\backslash C$ is open is false. Consider $X = (-1,1]$ and $C = (-1,0]$. Then $C$ is closed in $X$, but $X\backslash C = (0,1]$ is not open. In fact, it is correct to say that $C\subset X$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $X\backslash C$ is open in $X$.

@Euclid It follows from the definition of subspace topology (with the caveat that we are considering open in $Y$ for the consequent).

That's practically the definition of "open" in a subspace topology. @Euclid

The fact

If $A, Y \subseteq X$, and $A$ is closed in $X$, then $Y \cap A$ is closed in $Y$ under the subspace topology.

is true for any space $X$. To show it, simply observe that from set theory,
$$Y - Y \cap A = Y \cap (X - A)$$
By hypothesis, $A \subseteq X$ is closed, so $X - A$ is open (in $X$, of course). Then by definition of the subspace topology, $Y \cap (X - A)$ is open in $Y$. Hence $Y \cap A = Y - Y \cap (X - A)$ must be closed (in $Y$), and we are done.
